# How to best set a CSS3 transition to none?

Tags: html, css, properties, css-transitions

How would I make it so a CSS transition doesn't work inside a media-query, or in any other case? For example:

```
@media (min-width: 200px) {
    element {
        transition: width 1s;
    }   
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    element {
        transition: none; // SET TO NO TRANSITION
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can set the **transition-property** to **none**. This way, no transition effect will be applied.

Like this:

```
-webkit-transition-property: none;
-moz-transition-property: none;
-o-transition-property: none;
transition-property: none;
```

Comment: Can't you just set `transition: none` (plus prefixes if needed)?

Comment: What about `transition: unset`? Wouldn't that be similar to marking the property as none?

Comment: @tomekwi You could, but that is a *shorthand property* that has to get expanded by the interpreter.  Setting `transition-property` does not require that wasteful expansion.

Answer (score 12):

Even better than setting **transition-property** to **none** is setting **transition-duration** to **0s**.

This is the cross-browser code:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0s;
-o-transition-duration: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
```

Why is this better?  Because, by default, standards-compliant browsers (such as Firefox) set **transition-property** to **all** for each element.  They also set **transition-duration** to **0s**.  Thus, by setting **transition-duration** to **0s**, you are most closely matching how the browser defines an element without a transition.

Setting the **transition-duration** to the default **0s** renders the **transition-property** irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

```
transition: width 0s
```

Should do the trick - as it's basically saying there is a transition, but 0s is too quick to see it!

Comment: not really a solution, if your transition is scaling the element