# Temporarily make element invisible

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using the `document.elementFromPoint` API to get an element that is at a point. But I do not want to have all elements -- some are not qualified, like `inline` elements. Therefore, I am making unqualified elements temporarily invisible in order to grab the element that is beneath it.

Here is a code excerpt.

```
import { elementQualified, elementFromPoint } from './utils';

function makeInvisible(element) {
  let oldVisibility = element.style.visibility;

  /* this is supposed to make the element invisible immediately, without
   * any delay. When a `transition` property is set which includes the
   * `visibility` property, this is sometimes unfortunately not the case. */
  element.style.visibility = "hidden";

  /* this is the undo function being called at the end. */
  return () => {
    element.style.visibility = oldVisibility;
  };
}

export default function(x, y) {
  var undo = [], element, last;

  /* in a loop, we grab the top-most element that is at a certain coordinate
   * inside the viewport. The `last` variable is preventing an infinite loop
   * in cases, where `makeInvisible()` does not work. */
  while (((element = elementFromPoint(x, y)) !== null) && (last !== element)) {
    /*
     * In order to be qualified, this element including its ancestors must
     * all be qualified. For instance, if this is a block element but the
     * parent for some reason is an inline element, this is not desired. */
    if (withAncestors(element).every(elementQualified)) {
        break;
    }

    /* if the element is not qualified, we make it invisible and add it to the
     * start of the `undo` array which is being batch-called after this loop. */
    undo.unshift(makeInvisible(element));

    /* and the loop protection */
    last = element;
  }

  /* undo all changes */
  undo.forEach((fn) => fn());

  /* check if we broke the loop or we have selected the topmost element
   * in which case we discard the result. */
  if ((last === element) || (element === document.documentElement)) {
    return null;
  }

  return element;
}
```

If the element that is supposed to become invisible has a `transition` property set which includes the `visibility` property, it will not become invisible immediately. Take for instance `transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out`. After setting `element.style.visibility` to `hidden`, it will take `0.3s` after which the element is actually invisible and `document.elementFromPoint` would select the element beneath it. As a result, the loop is breaking because `document.elementFromPoint` is returning two times the identical element.

I am not intending to temporarily set the `display` property because it causes layout changes and I am building a tool for which layout changes do not work.

Comment: Cant you remove the transition before setting the element to invisible and set it back once you are done?

Comment: "_... display property ... causes layout changes_" It doesn't, when you're doing all the DOM handling synchronously, and set everything back as it was before giving browser a chance to render the page. Hence Setting `display: none` in a script would not be shown on the page, if you remove the styling before the script ends.

Comment: I have tried the `display: none` option before. It causes some layout changes and scrolling issues for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lain suggested in the comments, [disable transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851153/5922436) on the element in `makeInvisible`, then have a timeout (1ms should be sufficient) that resets the transition property

Comment: I have found out that it's possible to do this without a timeout for re-enabling the transition. I simply set the `visibility` to the old value and then cause a layout reflow before setting the `transition` property.